# BeautifulSoup Extract Text from a Paragraph and Split Text by <br/>

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to BeauitfulSoup.

How would I be able to extract the text in a paragraph from an html source code, split the text whenever there is a <br/>, and store it into an array such that each element in the array is a chunk from the paragraph text (that was split by a <br/>)?

For example, for the following paragraph:

```
<p>
    <strong>Pancakes</strong>
    <br/> 
    A <strong>delicious</strong> type of food
    <br/>
</p>
```

I would like it to be stored into the following array:

```
['Pancakes', 'A delicious type of food']
```

What I have tried is:

```
import bs4 as bs

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup("<p>Pancakes<br/> A delicious type of food<br/></p>")
p = soup.findAll('p')
p[0] = p[0].getText()
print(p)
```

but this outputs an array with only one element:

```
['Pancakes A delicious type of food']
```

What is a way to code it so that I can get an array that contains the paragraph text split by any <br/> in the paragraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '<p>Pancakes<br/> A delicious type of food<br/></p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
p = soup.findAll('p')
result = [str(child).strip() for child in p[0].children
            if isinstance(child, NavigableString)]
```

Update for deep recursive

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

html = "<p><strong>Pancakes</strong><br/> A <strong>delicious</strong> type of food<br/></p>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find('p').find_all(text=True, recursive=True)
```

Update again for text split only by <br>

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

html = "<p><strong>Pancakes</strong><br/> A <strong>delicious</strong> type of food<br/></p>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = ''
for child in soup.find_all('p')[0]:
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
        text += str(child).strip()
    elif isinstance(child, Tag):
        if child.name != 'br':
            text += child.text.strip()
        else:
            text += '\n'

result = text.strip().split('\n')
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However, I was wondering if it would be possible to make it not "delete" other tags in the paragraph. For example, using you code, if the paragraph was "<p><strong>Pancakes</strong><br/> A <strong>delicious</strong> type of food<br/></p>", it would output "['A', 'type of food']" instead of ['Pancakes', 'A delicious type of food'].

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. The output looks like it is "['Pancakes', ' A ', 'delicious', ' type of food.']", but I am still looking for "['Pancakes', 'A delicious type of food']". I am only looking to split the text at the <br/>s and not any other tags.

Comment: ['Pancakes A delicious type of food'] ? Are your sure ?, not ['Pancakes', 'A delicious type of food'] ?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Yes, I am looking for the output ['Pancakes', 'A delicious type of food']

Comment: Update again as above

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this whilst having a similar issue. This was my solution...
A simple way is to replace the line

p[0] = p[0].getText()

with

p[0].getText('#').split('#')

Result is:
['Pancakes', ' A delicious type of food']

Obv choose a character/characters that won't appear in the text

Comment: Would be great to take a read of how to [edit] and format your post. In addition - Have you really tested your code?